# Regex in R: extract comma separated keywords from string

Tags: r, regex

I want to know if it is possible to extract keywords from a string that are separated by a comma. For example, if the text says

`This is a random text Keywords: a, b, c Hi stack overflow`

It should return

`a, b, c`

I think this should be easy if the keywords are just one word. In that case, you could tell regex to stop looking for words if the word is not followed by a comma (which means you're at the end of the list of keywords).
However, what if keywords consist of multiple words? e.g. the text says

`Hi stackoverflow Keywords: a, b, stack overflow Some more text`

It should return

`a, b, stack overflow`

Note that the first word after the list of keywords starts with a capital, so is it possible to make use of that and tell regex to look for words up until the point where a capital letter has been found?

Data

```
x <- c(
  'This is a random text Keywords: a, b, c Hi stack overflow',
  'Hi stackoverflow Keywords: a, b, stack overflow Some more text'
)
```

Comment: What do you do with `"a, b, c unwanted text"`

Comment: `gsub(':\\s*([a-z, ]+?)\\s*[A-Z]|.', '\\1', x)`

Answer (score 0):

The following *regex* would do the job :

```
.*?(?:Keywords:?\s)(.*?,.*?,.*?(?<!,)(?=\s[A-Z])).*?$
```

*see* ***[demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/JKfFLl/6)***

**r**

```
x <- c(
  'This is a random text Keywords AA, bB, CC Hi stack overflow',
  'Hi stackoverflow Keywords: a, b, STaCk oVerFlow Some more text'
)
gsub('.*?(?:Keywords:?\\s)(.*?,.*?,.*?(?<!,)(?=\\s[A-Z])).*?$','\\1', x, perl=T)
```

Comment: When I do `gsub("(?-i)(?<=:\\s).*?,.*?,.*?(?=\\s[A-Z])", "\\1", x)` it says invalid regexp?

Comment: @vdvaxel check updated answer. now it should work fine :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! One more question though: what if the text just says `Keywords` without `:`, it doesn't work? And what if the keywords themselves have capital letters?

Comment: @vdvaxel `"keywords themselves have capital letters"` means? aA, bB, cC?

Comment: No they start with a capital letter (unfortunately)

Comment: @vdvaxel like this .. Stack overflow? or stack Overflow?

Comment: Either the first word and the second word or just the first word

Comment: @vdvaxel if first word is capital then its possible to capture but not the second word, as its the key feature that separates keywords from other words.
and yes Keywords w/o `:` will work

Comment: And what if I use a heuristic where the number of words for a keyword is at most 2?

Comment: @vdvaxel yes, possible

Comment: Thanks, this has already helped me a lot! However, how should the regex change if there are 2nd words with capital letters? Is it possible?

Comment: @vdvaxel No its not possible in this case. since that's the only way to distinguish between a keyword and a general word.

Answer (score 0):

This regex `[a-z]+\s*(?:,\s*(?:\s*[a-z])+)+` will get a group of keywords as a string.
Each match has to be split by comma to get the individual keywords.

```
 [a-z]+                        # 1st keyword
 \s*                           # optional space
 (?:                           # Group start, remaining keywords
      ,                             # comma
      \s*                           # optional space
      (?:                           # Group start
           \s*                           # optional space
           [a-z]                         # letter
      )+                            # Group end, 1 or more times
 )+                            # Group end, 1 or more times
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 32 , len 7 ) 
a, b, c  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 86 , len 19 ) 
a, b stack overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Look around before (?<=\:), look around after (?=[A-Z]), extract (.*)

```
gsub('.*(?<=\\:)(.*)(?=[A-Z]).*','\\1',x,perl=T)
[1] " a, b, c "              " a, b, stack overflow "
```

Comment: I changed this to `.*(?<=Keywords\\:)(.*?)(?=[A-Z]).*` but this returns me an empty string?