# R regex regular expression: create list of characters from comma-separated values in a string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

suppose I have the following string in `R`:

```
x <- "one, two, three, four"
```

I would like to obtain the vector

```
c("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

Is it possible to do this with regular expressions? I tried the examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492217/regex-in-r-extract-comma-separated-keywords-from-string) but nothing worked.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a solution without `regex`. That is `strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]]`. But it would still be nice to have one with `regex`

Comment: Is there any reason for regex, like in your actual use? The advantage of constructing a pattern manually over just the base `strsplit` might be more clear if you had an example of it

Comment: Well part of it was cause I wanted to learn a bit more about regex. But I guess I could just accept one of these answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, ", "))
```

Data:

```
x <- "one, two, three, four"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stringr` package can do this ...

```
library(stringr)
str_split("one, two, three, four", ", ")
```